# My AlarmManager fires the alarm immediately

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Though this question is repeated over and over here on SO, but non of the solutions are working, in the code below it should fire for the first time after 10 seconds from launching my activity, but it launch immediately. And I'm using FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so there's no past time to fire immediately as I'm not setting it at specific hour/minute/sec. Could you please bring my attention to what I'm missing.

I'm testing on Android 5.0 Targeting API 4.0+

- compileSdkVersion 23
- minSdkVersion 16
- targetSdkVersion 23

  ```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, check.class);
  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
  ```

  am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, 10000, (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY / 8), pi);

**And this is my check.class in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".Check"
        android:exported="false" />
```

Comment: Seriously people who added -1 for the question, why? Do you know the answer? Then share it, and I explained that I looked for the answers here and they are not working, down vote is not a toy you play it just because you can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`10000` on the real time clock is always going to be in the past, so your alarm fires immediately. You want `System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000` as the second argument in the `setRepeating()` call.

I would point out that `setRepeating()` is inexact as of KitKat, so the actual time the alarm fires may be off. If it matters, use the `setExact()` method instead, setting the alarm again for the desired interval each time it fires.

Comment: Thank you Mike for the explanation, especially the second part / edit, that was the reason I thought (during applying others solutions on the same question) that System.currentTimeMillis() will be added to the 10000 to first trigger. Again thank you, and yes it is not exact but it will do for the check purpose.